# File Picker excel file (.CSV) Flutter

Tags: csv, flutter

I want to have a page that can upload excel .csv file into the page.  Therefore, I use the file picker to select the file but I am unable to select the CSV file. The Raised Button navigate me to google drive and select the file, I am able to upload others file type of files except for CSV file. How can I upload a CSV file to the Flutter page?

Problem 2: When I am navigated to google drive, I am unable to go back to the upload page and it will show an error.

**string_patch.dart**
String operator +(String other) native "String_concat";
The exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s))

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class UploadPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyUploadPageState createState() => new _MyUploadPageState();
}

class _MyUploadPageState extends State<UploadPage> {
  String _filePath;

  void getFilePath() async {
    try {
      String filePath = await FilePicker.getFilePath();
      if (filePath == '') {
        return;
      }
      print("File path: " + filePath);
      setState(() {
        this._filePath = filePath;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Error while picking the file: " + e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Upload CSV File'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new ButtonBar(
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => {},
                color: Colors.purple,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: _filePath == null
                    ? new Text('No file selected.')
                    : new Text('Path' + _filePath),
              ), // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
              new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: getFilePath,
                child: new Icon(Icons.sd_storage),
                color: Colors.purple,
              )
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use packages like CSV, csv_reader or even pdftron which will allow you to get all types of files even pptx with editing features like signature and stamp too.

Or I you want it to convert the CSV file into table or list then
full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: TableLayout(),
    );
  }
}


class TableLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableLayoutState createState() => _TableLayoutState();
}

class _TableLayoutState extends State<TableLayout> {
  List<List<dynamic>> data = [];
  loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/ford.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
    print(csvTable);
    data = csvTable;
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          onPressed: () async {
            await loadAsset();
            //print(data);
          }),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Table Layout and CSV"),
      ),

      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Table(
          columnWidths: {
            0: FixedColumnWidth(100.0),
            1: FixedColumnWidth(200.0),
          },
          border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0),
          children: data.map((item) {
            return TableRow(
                children: item.map((row) {
                  return Container(
                    color:
                    row.toString().contains("NA") ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        row.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList());
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

WORKING DEMO

[Working Demo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPjoy.gif)

[Working Demo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pogYv.png)

Comment: Hi, if I want to load the excel file that I selected from google drive? how should I do?

Comment: You can upload that excel file to firebase storage and when needed get it from there and load it in your app.

Comment: Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Unable to load asset: assets/ford.csv)  How to solve this problem .?

Comment: you need to add ford.csv to assets folder. Keep the assets folder outside the lib and define assets in pubspec.yaml

Comment: It shows this error "Table contains irregular row length. Every Tablerow in the table must have the same number of children, so that child is filled. Otherwise, the table will contain holes." I have 5 columns and 26 rows in my CSV file.

Comment: Each row must have same number of child columns and every column must have same number of child rows otherwise one place will be left blank thats the reasons you are getting this error. Instead of leaving blank give dash in that cell.

Comment: Okay. I get it. Do you know how to read the CSV file in the flutter and show how many records are inserted successfully into the database? I am able to upload the CSV file already but how to read the data from the CSV file? Do you have any example code?

Comment: Do you want to store children data under each one or something like that? Like keeping I'd, name and email id of each user and there are about 10 users something like that? If so then use salute or if you want to use CSV then use CSV package available

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, I am able to pick CSV files correctly.
I tried to pick a file both on GoogleDrive, or locally, both work.

Is it possible that your file is corrupted?

For your second question, if you cancel the file pick, the method `getFilePath` will return `null`.

In this case, the line :

```dart
print("File path: " + filePath);
```

raises an exception, since it can't add a `String` with a `null`.

Try to modify your previous `if` statement:

```dart
if (filePath == null || filePath == '') {
    return;
}
```

I tried it, I have no longer the error.

Comment: Hi , this code can pick the file correctly but the problem is i dont know how to read the file and print in console . After that , i also need to upload the data inside the excel into cloud firestore collection....